# RecyclerViewAdapter with list inside of list (grouping)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

(Kotlin-Android) 
I have a data class which is

```
data class ModelGroup(var teams: List<Model>, var groupName: String?)

data class Model(
    var cook: Cook?
)
```

I have a RecyclerView (gridLayoutManager) and each grid has a header (groupName).
Those grids are the ModelGroups and those groups comes from a REST API.
My adapter receives a List.

I also have two viewholders (1 for Header, 1 for Cook).

The problem is how to know if its an header or an cook object  in getItemViewType and how to bind the cook object that is inside of a list.

PS: I don't want to use any libraries!

```
class ModelGroupAdapter(
    private val context: Context?,
    private var modelGroups: List<ModelGroup>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private var selectedItem: Int = -1

companion object {
    private const val HEADER_VIEW_TYPE = 0
    private const val COOK_VIEW_TYPE = 1
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val headerViewHolder =
        HeaderViewholder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_shield_header, parent, false))
    val shieldViewHolder =
        CookViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_cook, parent, false))
    return when (viewType) {
        HEADER_VIEW_TYPE -> headerViewHolder
        COOK_VIEW_TYPE -> cookViewHolder
        else -> headerViewHolder
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    var count = 0
    for (group in teamGroups) {
        count += group.teams.size
    }
    return count + teamGroups.size
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    // how to know if its a header or a group.team.cook
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder is CookViewHolder) {
        context?.let {
            holder.bind(
                it,
                position,
                // how to get the current cook object by position?
            )
        }
    } else if (holder is HeaderViewholder) {
        context?.let { holder.bind(getHeaderText(position)) }
    }
}


inner class HeaderViewholder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val title = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_shield_header_title)

    fun bind(groupName: String) {
        title.text = groupName
    }
}

inner class CookViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val image = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_cook)

    fun bind(context: Context, position: Int, cook: Cook?) {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you should have a parameter in your api response to be able to differentiate

Comment: but my json comes like: [ {group1: items: [ ], groupName: "first"}, { group2: items[], groupName: "second"}, ....] It's nested

Comment: If it doesn't have the parameter, then ask with your api developer how to differentiate